# Can we deduce the (a^b)^c mod from the partial information a^b mod d and a^c mod d in Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

In Diffie-Hellman, the goal is to find:

$$(a^b)^c \mod d \equiv (a^c)^b \mod d$$

Alice has $b$ and Bob has $c$. $a$ and $b$ is pre-determined and known to Eve.

Exponentiation property of mod says that it is the same as:

$$(a^c \mod d)^b \mod d \equiv (a^b \mod d)^c \mod d$$

which is the key to making this work. This can be easily proved using binomial theorem for example.

Alice transmits $a^b \mod d$ and Bob transmits $a^c \mod d$.

Alice creates his key using:

$$(a^c \mod d)^b \mod d$$

Bob creates his key using:

$$(a^b \mod d)^c \mod d$$

which are same.

My question is, there is no known way to deduce this from $a^b \mod d$ and $a^c \mod d$, i.e the transmitted messages which Eve is listening to?

The reason for this doubt is that there is *some* 'reduced' information in the transmitted information, and Eve has access to both these transmitted information. So I was wondering if it can be constructed somehow?

Comment: No, not really.  That’s why it works.  You can look up the Diffie-Hellman problem, which is what this is.

Comment: @Randall, Thanks a quick question though, does Eve see a^b and a^c or the mod d of these values? I think it is the latter, but wiki says about the former.

Comment: Eve sees everything mod $d$.  We don't always say so, but it's implied.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is called the `Discrete Logarithm Problem` (DLP) and well studied and research still working.

If you want look to the problem with a nice overview, look at the Joux nice [paper](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/doc/discretelogs2014.pdf). From the conclusion;

> The most difficult challenge for discrete logarithms is probably the
>   **search for a subexponential algorithm** that would apply to general
>   elliptic curves defined over large characteristic fields. However,
>   even finding new Index Calculus algorithms to cover additional special
>   cases of curves is already a very challenging and fascinating problem
>   in this field of research.

And this [nice question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/45164/how-hard-is-the-dlp-in-that-simple-group) might give you some idea, too.

Apart from the solving the DLP, there is a [man in the middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) for Diffie-Hellman key exchange.

Comment: OP's question is really about the Diffie-Hellman problem, which is potentially harder than DLP.  A solution to DLP solves DHP, but we don't know about the converse.